# JQuery Remove comes back after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I am using JQuery remove and when the page is refreshed it brings the removed item back

Does anyone have any idea why? I need this to stay hidden/removed from page.

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and ($counter < $maximumAmount))  
 {      
   echo "<div id='div1'>"."".$row["1"].""."<img src=/".$row['2']."' width='150' height='150' />"."<br><br>".$row["3"]."

<form method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='ID' value= '".$row['ID']."'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='' id='button' ></form></div>";
```

Comment: It's because jquery affects the DOM client side (the changes aren't automatically sent to the server) you would need to send a request to the server to remove the record associated with the div in question

Comment: why you choose mysql tag for this question

Comment: Jquery is just like computer RAM. It will reset after refresh. You can try PHP session or Cookies for this.

Comment: Can I install more jquery into my pc?

Comment: Use sessionStorage to save the state of this element, and on refresh you need to check it and remove again, if this state is positive

Comment: dude, use ajax or something for deleting /setting flag for this

Comment: @Gyan this sounds best as i just want it off the page, dont need it deleted in database etc. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: @sarathsrajendran HI, how can this be done?

Comment: This question received four upvotes, huh? Looks fishy…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any operation made with jQuery has effect only during the lifetime of the current page. Once you reload the page, all those changes will be lost.

If you want that the button stay hidden, you need to store that information somewhere. You could make a request to the server and store it in a preference, so next time you reload your PHP code can hide the button. You could also use `localStorage` to keep it hidden:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div1Removed = localStorage.getItem('div1_removed');
    if (div1Removed) {
        $("#div1").remove();
    } else {
        $("#div1").show();
    }
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").remove();
        localStorage.setItem('div1_removed', 'true');
    });
});
</script>
```

In the PHP code, we add `display: hidden` to the div, so it is initially hidden. When the page loads, the JavaScript code will check whether it should be visible or not. If it should, then it makes it visible. If it shouldn't, then it removes it completely.

```
while($dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and ($cnt < $max))  
 {      
   echo "<div id='div1' style='display: hidden;'>"."".$dbRow["Name"]."</h4><br>"."<br><img src=/".$dbRow['Picture']."' width='150' height='150' />"."<br><br>".$dbRow["Instructions"]."

<form method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='MealID' value= '".$dbRow['MealID']."'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Complete' id='button' ></form></div>";            
$cnt++;
```

Comment: I added the Javascript code and it works! Do you think i still need the display:hidden?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're trying to achieve. Is isn't necessary per se, but if you don't include it, users could see the div briefly during page load, and then it may disappear, so I'd suggest you to use it.

Comment: Hi, Okay thank you. What seems to have happened is that the javscript then does allow the other function to perform? It's basically just when button is selected it displays  a line of text?